# App Store Trending Searches RSS Feed

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, rss

Apple offers quite a few RSS feeds for searching the App Store in various ways (http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---rss-feed-generator.html for example).

Does anyone know how to access the Trending Searches terms that appear on the App Store app when clicking the Search button?  I'd like to get programmatic access to this list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish. SensorTower sells that info.